# Access ListViewItem properties within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

If I have a DataTemplate in my ListView, how do I access the ListViewItem properties? Since ListViewItem elements are created at runtime, how does one create new properies within the DataTemplate?

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        //Here you would place a Grid or some other UI element. It will be implicitly placed within an ListView Item at runtime, I think
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to add some properties to each ListViewItem which will be generated at runtime. How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "add some properties"  ?

Comment: If you populate the ListView by setting the ItemsSource property, the ItemTemplate is applied to every item. If you populate the Items collection directly, the ItemTemplate is applied only if the item is not a ListViewItem. See [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx)  for more info.

Comment: Thx for the response, but if I were to apply a style to the ListViewItem element, it would style each of the DataTemplate items, which goes to show that there IS a ListViewItem implicitly attached to each DataTemplate item. But because the ListViewItem is IMPLICITLY applied to these items at runtime, there does not seem to be a way to access the ListViewItem's properties to do things such as add a behavior to them, etc.

Comment: Agree with AnjumSKhan said, I don't what do you want to add.

Comment: possibly ItemContainerStyle may help you. Item container will be one level up of your data template. all the hover selected foreground color back ground color, effects are applied to this container.